# Actionscript equivalent of "eval"

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, eval

I'm looking for an Actionscript equivalent for Python / PHP / etc.'s `eval()` function, which dynamically executes code from an arbitrary string.

Comment: I was under the impression that `eval()` was discouraged in languages which still supported it.  AS2 supported `eval()`.  Are you trying to reference an object by its name?

Comment: There is no equivalent of `eval()` in AS3. What are you trying to do ?

Comment: No, I am not using `eval()` for unsafe reasons. I want it for debugging purposes - I want to add arbitrary eval()'ing to a debug console in a game. If there's no equivalent, just make that the answer so I can accept it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no native `eval()` function. I see only one hack to do it : create a bytecode at runtime and load it. If you really need it, there are some cool libs that will do it for you :

- http://eval.hurlant.com/
- http://code.google.com/p/as3scriptinglib/

Comment: I just wanted to reflectively get a class, and `flash.utils.getDefinitionByName` did the trick for me